# UILabel fails to update properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I am a beginner and working on an iOS app in Xcode (Swift). For some reason I can set the text in a UILabel just fine using its property .text but if I try and update it the label will only show the last value I set (??). For example, here is the code that gets executed when I click a button called myButton and try to set the text in the label called Display. The result is that only the fourth value ("Four") is displayed (after the three 2 second delays) as the UILabel stays blank until that point. The really odd thing is that if I remove everything but the first line (Display.text = "One") it will display it just fine. It is as if the compiler removes all but the last property setting for the label... Any help is appreciated!!

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any)
{
    Display.text = "One"
    sleep(2)
    Display.text = "Two"
    sleep(2)
    Display.text = "Three"
    sleep(2)
    Display.text = "Four"
}
```

Update: This code is just an example that demonstrates a problem I encountered in my real program. The sleep() call is to simulate a delay only. The problem is that I can't seem to set the UILabel's text twice.  In my code, I call a function that takes time to execute so I want to display "Wait..." in the label until it is done and then I want to display the result in the same label. But no luck...

Update 2: I found this in Apples documentation: "You provide the content for a label by assigning either a NSString object to the text property, or an NSAttributedString object to the attributedText property. The label **displays the most recently set of these properties**." Most recent? That seems to be my problem.How can I force it to update on-demand???

Comment: Never, ever sleep on the main thread. It just blocks the thread, this is why you only see the last update. Use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` instead

Comment: start propert names with small letter `display`

Comment: I should have added that this code snippet is just an example. I don't use sleep() in my code, I call a function that takes time to execute so I want to display "Wait..." in the label until it is done. But my code had this oddity so I simplified it here with the sleep(). Good points though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `sleep` it blocks the main thread

```
let arr = ["one","two","three","four"]
var counter = 0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:2.0, repeats:true) { timer in
    self.counter += 1
    if counter < self.arr.count {
       self.display.text = self.arr[counter]
    }
    else {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Or use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`

```
arr.indices.forEach {
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double( $0 * 2) ) { 
      self.display.text = self.arr[$0]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I am sorry my question was not very clear. This is just a simple code snippet that behaves like my code. The real problem is this: When I hit a button I want to display "Wait..." in the UILabel. It will then execute code that can take 1-3 seconds or so. When done I want the result to be displayed in the same label. However, my code fails to show the "Wait..." and only display the result. Just like my example above that uses the sleep() to simulate a delay. Any idea of how I can write to the .text twice in the code and have both show up (before/after)?

Comment: Using timers here is a bad idea. The `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` should be the only solution, not "Or"

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked. But it uses a timer and that is not what I have (unfortunate formulation of my example) so I am going to ask separate question in a new thread as I now know that this is related to threads and updates.